# Angular 2 - TypeError undefined is not a function for Array includes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, tsconfig

My Angular 2 project was created with angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.30.  I am using the ngx-charts version 4.1.2 library.  The bar chart component is working fine but when I add a line chart, a TypeError exception is thrown when I run the application.  The error is the "includes" function in line 240 of [line-chart.component.ts][1] source file when running in Chrome version 38.  The line chart appears correctly in Firefox

```
if (!values.includes(d.name)) {
    values.push(d.name);
}
```

How do I make the array include function known to my application?

In my tsconfig.json file I have

```
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
```

My package.json file contains the following

```
{
  "name": "dashboards",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^4.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.3",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.30",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.5",
    "@types/d3": "^4.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.7.0",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.4.0",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "ts-node": "1.7.2",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  }
}
```

My polyfills.ts file contains

```
import 'core-js/es6/array';
```

I've looked through the ngx-charts demo and other examples but I can't figure out why I am receiving the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem.  The polyfills.ts file contained

```
import 'core-js/es6/array';
```

I needed to add

```
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

to the file.

I'm thinking this is due to the version of Chrome installed on my corporate PC. It is version 38.  This [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) page for Array.includes states that support for Chrome is in version 47.